# Using Magento for Client-to-Client service

Tags: magento-1.7, virtual

I am starting a website where my users will be able to purchase virtual products but also be able to sell them. I look around for a Magento extension, but I haven't found any. Am I using the right wording, meaning is Client-to-Client the right terminology? Also would you recommend that I use Magento for this type of service?

Comment: I don't believe that I've seen any pre-made extensions for this, but you may want to also search for 'person to person' or its abbreviation p2p.

Answer (score 1):

Have not seen such extension, but I have copied Enterprise extension, that allow to separate admins per store, to community. And so - you can create separate store for each user who wish to sell. So maybe it can help with your idea ?

Comment: I was actually thinking of using the Magento RestFul API. And just create a module for a section for the client where he/she can sell is virtual product.

Comment: ok. are you searching for somebody to develop such module? our team have developed big amount of modules before and we will be happy to help

Comment: I am developer myself. And I am reading on how to build Magento extensions. I just wanted to make sure that nobody as ever done this so that I don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Paul do you have a link?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, Paul... I might be able to have multiple online stores with Magento Enterprise?